# animating width of div using percentages width Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following working code and I want to change it as so it uses percentages for width intead of 400px. How could I acomplish that?
Specifically, I want it to go from an intial width of 25%  to 0 and back to 25% once the button is clicked again. 
Also, using the same show_hide_button how could I change the width of an aditional div as so it will switch between 75% and 100%. 75% intial, 100% when button is clicked and back to 75% when button is clicked again.

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#show_hide_button').click( function() {
        var toggleWidth = $("#some_box").width() == 400 ? "0" : "400px";
        $('#some_box').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
    });
});
```

I will really appreciate any help!

Comment: Im pretty sure you cdan animate pourcentage value : `$("#some_box").width() == 400 ? "0%" : "25%";` Edit: The if have to change.

Comment: @Karl You are right that could work, but after clicking the botton twice the width would not match 400 again so I stops working and It doesn't seem to work if I replace the 400 with a percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

**Update**: This should work

CSS:

```
#some_box {
    background: #fc0;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
}
#some_other_box {
    background: #0cf;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

JS:

```
var collapsed = false;
$('#show_hide_button').click(function() {
    if(!collapsed){
        $('#some_box').animate({width: '0%'});
        $('#some_other_box').animate({width: '100%'});
    } else {
        $('#some_box').animate({width: '25%'});
        $('#some_other_box').animate({width: '75%'});
    }
    collapsed = !collapsed;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/xLHb8/

**original answer**:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#show_hide_button').click( function() {
        $('#some_box').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/xLHb8/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more thing. How would I animate the additional div with same button switching between 75% and 100%?

Comment: I just edited my answer to work with more recent versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As discuted in the comment, you can animate the width as a percentage. Now, to know if the width is 0% or 25%, i suggest you to work with class. Just like that :

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#show_hide_button').click( function() {
        var toggleWidth = $("#some_box").hasClass('expanded') ? "0%" : "25%";
        $('#some_box').stop().animate({ width: toggleWidth }, function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
        });
    });
});
```

Here a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/umCyy/

Answer (score -1):

I'm fairly knew here but I'll give it a go.

Your answer would be to change the scale factor.

Simple tutorial for a regular bar:

First of all, it works by taking the percent you've calculated lets say "50%", then you take the width of the object and make sure "100" width is full (unless you want to make it more complicated)
As you get more percentage have it go up by **one** (unless you made it complicated).

As of the jquery, I'm not familiar with, I've answer as best as I can, hopefully from there you can get it working.
Also, there are many similar scripts online you could look into.